# Win32 select/poll/eof/ANYTHING?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, mfc

Using the standard Win32 file I/O API's (CreateFile/ReadFile/etc), I'm trying to wait for a file to become readable, or for an exception to occur on the file.  If Windows had any decent POSIX support, I could just do:

```
select(file_count, files_waiting_for_read, NULL, files_waiting_for_excpt, NULL, NULL);
```

And select will return when there's anything interesting on some of the files.  Windows doesn't support select or poll. Fine.  I figured I could take the file and do something like:

```
while(eof(file_descriptor))
{
    Sleep(100);
}
```

The above loop would exit when more data is available to be read.  But nope, Windows doesn't have an equivalent of eof() either!  I could possibly call ReadFile() on the file, and determine if it's at the eof that way. But, then I'd have to handle the reading at that point in time -- I'm hoping to simply be able to figure out that a file is readable, without actually reading it.

What are my options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows has a completely different architecture for asynchronous I/O. You will need to use [overlapped I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686358(VS.85).aspx) with or without the related [I/O completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198(VS.85).aspx).

Note that the standard Winsock interface does have a POSIX-like `select()` function, but that only works with network sockets.

Comment: Wow I hate Windows.  Everything that should be simple isn't.  Is there really no 'GetEndOfFile' type of function?  I see there's a SetEndOfFile :(

Comment: @Andrew, Windows is not POSIX compliant.

Comment: Different doesn't mean inferior; obviously with one model some things may be simpler and other more complicated. You just have to think about the same thing from a different perspective.

Comment: You might want to look at GetFileSize: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364955(VS.85).aspx to find the end of file.

First hit on a search for "get file size".

Answer (score 1):

I am answering six year later here goes anyway: I found WSAPoll similar to *nix poll. Here link to MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741669(v=vs.85).aspx
Iwas added to Vista and later versions and works with sockets.

Answer (score 1):

It's been over a decade but I just need to correct you about something: regular (disk) files are always ready to read and write according to POSIX, so select or poll will simply return immediately even though a subsequent call to read() or write() may block or fail (similarly, O_NONBLOCK does nothing for disk files).

> Regular files shall always poll TRUE for reading and writing.

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/poll.html

Windows has always provided first-class asynchronous I/O facilities for regular files, with various approaches depending on your application type. In only the past handful of years are Unix-based OSes starting to catch up (Linux with io_uring, FreeBSD with the only true async kernel-based POSIX AIO support).

also eof() is not posix, but MSVCRT actually does have that function (as _eof) in io.h which exists for Unix compatibility.